# Does SerializedShuffleHandle and UnsafeShuffleWriter support to order by partitionId and key

Tags: apache-spark

I am reading the spark source code about shuffle. The shuffle handle is chozen based on the following check, defind in `SortShuffleManager#registerShuffle`,

The method definition is:

```
  override def registerShuffle[K, V, C](
      shuffleId: Int,
      dependency: ShuffleDependency[K, V, C]): ShuffleHandle = {
    if (SortShuffleWriter.shouldBypassMergeSort(conf, dependency)) {
      // If there are fewer than spark.shuffle.sort.bypassMergeThreshold partitions and we don't
      // need map-side aggregation, then write numPartitions files directly and just concatenate
      // them at the end. This avoids doing serialization and deserialization twice to merge
      // together the spilled files, which would happen with the normal code path. The downside is
      // having multiple files open at a time and thus more memory allocated to buffers.
      new BypassMergeSortShuffleHandle[K, V](
        shuffleId, dependency.asInstanceOf[ShuffleDependency[K, V, V]])
    } else if (SortShuffleManager.canUseSerializedShuffle(dependency)) {
      // Otherwise, try to buffer map outputs in a serialized form, since this is more efficient:
      new SerializedShuffleHandle[K, V](
        shuffleId, dependency.asInstanceOf[ShuffleDependency[K, V, V]])
    } else {
      // Otherwise, buffer map outputs in a deserialized form:
      new BaseShuffleHandle(shuffleId, dependency)
    }
  }
```

From the check path, there are situations that `SerializedShuffleHandle` will be used if key sorting is involved, such as using `RDD#sortByKey`to do global sorting.

But in the corresponding writer `UnsafeShuffleWriter` of  SerializedShuffleHandle, it looks to me that it only sort by partitionId, there are no code about sorting with RDD `key`.

I would ask whether UnsafeShuffleWriter supports to sort with partionId and key. If not, what happens for the shuffle selection logic, it should supports to do key ordering if SerializedShuffleHandle is chozen in some case.